# Dovecot - auth: Fatal: Unknown database driver 'pgsql'

Tags: postfix, postgresql, dovecot

I'm trying to configure Dovecot + Postfix + PostfixAdmin with postgresql support.
I successfully configured postfix to send emails to aliases for my domain, and now I want to configure actual mailboxes support on my server.
I followed the configuration options for database support on dovecot 2 wiki (http://wiki.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/SQL), dovecot starts without errors, but at the first attempt to connect by IMAP, dovecot complains on maillog:

```
auth: Fatal: Unknown database driver 'pgsql'
```

I'm sure dovecot has postgres support, here's the output for dovecot --build-options:

```
Build options: ioloop=epoll notify=inotify ipv6 openssl io_block_size=8192
Mail storages: cydir dbox maildir mbox mdbox raw shared
SQL driver plugins: mysql postgresql sqlite
Passdb: checkpassword ldap pam passwd passwd-file shadow sql
Userdb: checkpassword ldap(plugin) nss passwd prefetch passwd-file sql
```

Additional information:

**/etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-sql.conf.ext**

```
passdb {
  driver = pgsql
  # Path for SQL configuration file, see example-config/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  args = /etc/dovecot/conf.d/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
}
```

For driver section I tried: 'pgsql, 'postgresql' and 'sql', I always get the error.

**/etc/dovecot/conf.d/dovecot-sql.conf.ext**

```
connect = host=localhost dbname=postfix user=postfix password=secret
default_pass_scheme = CRYPT
password_query = SELECT userid as user, password FROM users WHERE userid = '%u'
user_query = SELECT '/home/'||home AS home, uid, gid FROM users WHERE userid = '%u'
```

Any idea about something I'm missing?
Thank you.

Comment: Fixed by myself. I was missing the dovecot-pgsql package. Pretty trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On CentOS 6 is necessary to install not only the dovecot package, but also the additional modules, in this case the package dovecot-pgsql is also needed for postgresql support.

The right syntax for the driver line in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-sql.conf.ext is:

```
driver = sql
```

and then the right driver is specified in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/dovecot-sql.conf.ext

```
driver = pgsql
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf` on my Fedora23 system has a section at the bottom for "Password and user databases":  
  
`!include auth-sql.conf.ext` might need to be uncommented also/instead.

Comment: `conf.d/` files are included from `dovecot.conf`